# Отмена стилей для :focus при :active

Tags: html, css

Всем привет!
Есть код:

```css
a.btn_other { text-decoration: none; }

.btn_other {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 5px;
  border: 1px solid rgba(160, 160, 160, .5);
  border-radius: 3px;
  background: #fff;
  color: #444;
}

.btn_other:hover {
  background: silver;
}

.btn_other:active {
  background: rgb(218, 218, 218);
  box-shadow: inset 1px 1.732px 1px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
}

.btn_other:focus {
  border-color: #09d;
  box-shadow: none;
}
```

```html
<a class="btn_other" href="#">Кнопка</a>
```

Реально ли сделать так, чтобы при нажатии на кнопку она не получала фокус, а получала его только при переходе к кнопке по Tab'у. 
На данный момент, при нажатии, кнопка получает стили для :active и для :focus одновременно.
Желательно это реализовать без JS.

Comment: Т. е. кнопка должна быть нажимаемой, но фокус не сохранять?

Comment: Да, именно так.

Comment: так пропишите отдельные стили для :active:focus

Comment: @lexxl, не поможет. `:active` исчезнет после отпускания мыши, а `:focus` останется.

Comment: Стоит покопать в сторону анимаций, но вообще, думаю, это невозможно.

Comment: В ответе отписался по поводу отмены стилей при помощи CSS

Answer (score 2):

Для тех кто ищет ответ в наши дни.

Обратите внимание на псевдо-классы CSS: :focus-within & :focus-visible

Answer (score 1):

Можно и без использования JS:

```
.btn_other:active, .btn_other:focus{
  all: initial;
  * {
    all: unset;
  }
}
```

P.S. Поддержка: Chrome 37>, Firefox 27>, IE 11, Opera 24>

Подробно тут: [Читать](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/all)

 Удачного кодинга...

Answer (score 0):

С помощью `CSS` это реализовать не получиться, можно только через `JavaScript` отлавливать эти события и добавлять класс, когда это необходимо, если вы конечно допускаете использование `js` в данном случаи.

Answer (score 0):

Я решил эту задачу без JS.

Всё дело в расположении селекторов в css. Плюс я использовал 2 псевдоэлемента.

Вставлю код из своего проекта.

```css
.banner__btn {
  position: relative;
  padding: 23px 35px;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 700;
  line-height: 25px;
  color: white;
  background: #9D5CD0;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 100px;
}

.banner__btn::before {
  display: none;
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: -5px;
  right: -5px;
  bottom: -4px;
  left: -5px;
  border: 2px solid #C283F3;
  border-radius: 100px;
}

.banner__btn::after {
  display: none;
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  border: 3px solid #D1A9F0;
  border-radius: 100px;
}

.banner__btn:hover {
  padding: 20px 32px;
  border: 3px solid #D1A9F0;
}

.banner__btn:active {
  padding: 20px 32px;
  background: #7943A4;
  border: 3px solid #D1A9F0;
}

.banner__btn:focus {
  padding: 23px 35px;
  outline: none;
  border: none;
}

.banner__btn:focus.banner__btn::before {
  display: block;
}

.banner__btn:active.banner__btn::before {
  display: none;
}

.banner__btn:active.banner__btn::after {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<a href="#map" class="banner__btn">
          Подписаться на рассылку
          </a>
```